# Fancybox 2 action when on last image

Tags: jquery, fancybox

I have just updated to Fancybox 2 and find it much better than previous version.

What I would like to know is that if there's a way to trigger a function when it reaches the last element in gallery...right now it loops, but I would like to call back another function to load more pictures!

Thank you in advance, 
Nicolo'

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can try:

```
$('.fancylink').fancybox({
    loop: false,
    afterShow: function(){          
        if(this.index  == this.group.length - 1){
            alert('I am the last item of the gallery');
        }
    }
}); // fancybox
```

It will show the alert just right after the last element of the gallery has been shown.

Comment: That was great! When I'm at the last image, it calls my function and adds 20 more pictures to the page...now the problem is they won't be loaded in the fancybox :( how can I deal with it without reopening it?

Comment: are you adding to the links the same class of your fancybox selector? fancybox 2 can handle existing and dynamically added elements.

Comment: yea, same class and rel!!!You can watch it at theworldsmiling.com: just open the fancybox,navigate to the last picture,it'll add more pictures but they wont be displayed until u reload the fancybox :(

Answer (score 0):

For those who still uses the old version:

```
$("a[rel=group]").fancybox({
    onComplete  :   function(a,index) {
        var total = $("a[rel=group]").length - 1;
        if( index == total ){
            alert("last one, whats next?");
        }
    }
});
```