# Fancybox detect slideshow end

Tags: fancybox

I have videos in my fancybox. Is it possible to detect when slideshow has come to an end (so last video has finished)?

I have this code which detect start of last item, I could implement some code to detect video end, however I was wondering whether there is some quicker / more efficient way to detect fancybox slideshow finish?

```
afterShow: function(){          
    if(this.index == this.group.length - 1){
        alert('I am the last item of the gallery');
    }
}
```

Comment: There are 2 different things. Detecting when a fancybox gallery ends http://stackoverflow.com/a/8888198/1055987 (from where you got the code in your post) and detecting the end of a video inside fancybox. If it is a youtube video check http://stackoverflow.com/a/20863405/1055987

Comment: Yes, I know these are 2 different things. I was wondering is there more specific callback or method from which can determine slideshow end (start going from last slideshow item in fancybox to first one) so I can skip video end detection (and other possible caveats while doing so)